# How to use .js and .css file in SilverLight application

Tags: silverlight

I am using a customized alert message for my whole application which generates from a .js file and a .css file. I have also used silverlight in my application and shows MessageBox from silverlight with its default design. Now i want to customized that MessageBox in silverlight.

So, can anyone plz help me to know how to add js and css file to silverLight application and how to use it

Comment: Do you mean the JavaScript Silverlight MessageBox (e.g. for uncaught exceptions), or the ones actually in Silverlight (which do not use JS or CSS, but rather XAML and styles)?

Comment: Yes something like that. I am using 
    MessageBox.Show("Hello")

And i want to customized this messageBox design

Answer (score 1):

You can't change the built-in MessageBox style as easily as simply creating your own modal window. There are lots of custom messageboxes about and many have source code.

### e.g.

- [Creating a reusable MessageBox dialog.](http://community.devexpress.com/blogs/theonewith/archive/2008/08/06/custom-silverlight-controls-creating-a-reusable-messagebox-dialog-part-i.aspx)
- [Silverlight Modal Dialog With Custom User Controls](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/tutorials/aspnet/a01af6c8-c067-4fdd-bc01-d47cf3410feb/silverlight-modal-dialog.aspx)
- [Custom MessageBox Control for Silverlight 3](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/silverlight/CustomMessageBox.aspx)

Note: these are all Silverlight solutions, so you are authoring in XAML and with style, not using JS and CSS.

*It is also possible to call JS functions on the page from within Silverlight if you think that will be easier for your solution.*